# Add hover tooltip to javascript chart

Tags: javascript, charts

I've been working with the below code for years. It draws a simple chart based on data from other scripts. Sometimes I modify it for the actual task. Now I would like to add tooltip for the points with the actual value, but now idea how to do it.
I've been working with the below code for years. It draws a simple chart based on data from other scripts. Sometimes I modify it for the actual task. Now I would like to add tooltip for the points with the actual value, but now idea how to do it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Report</title>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id='mychart' width="1300" height="500" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>

<script>

//chart
function LineChart(config){
 // user defined properties
 this.canvas = document.getElementById(config.canvasId);
 this.minX = config.minX;
 this.minY = config.minY;
 this.maxX = config.maxX;
 this.maxY = config.maxY;
 this.unitsPerTickX = config.unitsPerTickX;
 this.unitsPerTickY = config.unitsPerTickY;
 this.caption = config.caption;
 this.Xcaption = config.Xcaption;
 this.Ycaption = config.Ycaption;
 this.title2 = config.title;
 this.label = config.labels;
  
 // constants
 this.padding = 10;
 this.tickSize = 10;
 this.axisColor = "#555";
 this.pointRadius = 3;
 this.font = "12pt Calibri";
 /*
  * measureText does not provide a text height
  * metric, so we'll have to hardcode a text height
  * value
  */
 this.fontHeight = 12;
 
 // relationships 
 this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
 this.rangeX = this.maxX - this.minY;
 this.rangeY = this.maxY - this.minY;
 this.numXTicks = Math.round(this.rangeX / this.unitsPerTickX);
 this.numYTicks = Math.round(this.rangeY / this.unitsPerTickY);
 this.x = this.getLongestValueWidth() + this.padding * 4;
 this.y = this.padding * 8;
 this.width = this.canvas.width - this.x - this.padding * 5;
 this.height = this.canvas.height - this.y - this.padding * 5 - this.fontHeight;
 this.scaleX = this.width / this.rangeX;
 this.scaleY = this.height / this.rangeY;
 
 // draw x y axis and tick marks
 this.drawXAxis();
 this.drawYAxis();

}

LineChart.prototype.getLongestValueWidth = function(){
 this.context.font = this.font;
 var longestValueWidth = 0;
 for (var n = 0; n <= this.numYTicks; n++) {
  var value = this.maxY - (n * this.unitsPerTickY);
  longestValueWidth = Math.max(longestValueWidth, this.context.measureText(value).width);
 }
 return longestValueWidth;
};

LineChart.prototype.drawXAxis = function(){
 var context = this.context;
 context.save();
 context.beginPath();
 context.moveTo(this.x, this.y + this.height);
 context.lineTo(this.x + this.width, this.y + this.height);
 context.strokeStyle = this.axisColor;
 context.lineWidth = 2;
 context.stroke();
 
 // draw tick marks
 for (var n = 0; n < this.numXTicks; n++) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo((n + 0) * this.width / this.numXTicks + this.x, this.y + this.height);
  context.lineTo((n + 0) * this.width / this.numXTicks + this.x, this.y + this.height - this.tickSize);
  context.stroke();
 }
 
 // draw labels
 context.font = this.font;
 context.fillStyle = "black";
 context.textAlign = "center";
 context.textBaseline = "middle";
 
 for (var n = 0; n < this.label.length; n++) {
  var label = this.label[n]
  //if (label>=24)  { label=label-24};
  context.save();
  context.translate((n + 0) * this.width / this.numXTicks + this.x, this.y + this.height + this.padding);
  context.fillText(label, 0, 0);
  context.restore();
 }
 
 // draw axis Labels
 context.textAlign = "right";
 context.textBaseline = "bottom";
 context.fillText(this.Xcaption, this.width + 8 * this.padding, this.height + 13 * this.padding);
 context.textAlign = "left";
 context.textBaseline = "top";
  context.fillText(this.Ycaption, 3 * this.padding ,  5 * this.padding );
 context.textAlign = "left";
 context.textBaseline = "bottom";
 context.font = 'bold 9pt Calibri';
 context.fillText(this.caption, 65 , this.height + 13 * this.padding);
 context.textAlign = "left";
 context.textBaseline = "top";
 context.font = 'bold 16pt Calibri';
  context.fillText(this.title2, (this.width /2)-80 , 10);

 context.restore();
};

LineChart.prototype.drawYAxis = function(){
 var context = this.context;
 context.save();
 context.save();
 context.beginPath();
 context.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
 context.lineTo(this.x, this.y + this.height);
 context.strokeStyle = this.axisColor;
 context.lineWidth = 2;
 context.stroke();
 context.restore();
 
 // draw tick marks
 for (var n = 0; n < this.numYTicks; n++) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(this.x, n * this.height / this.numYTicks + this.y);
  context.lineTo(this.x + this.tickSize, n * this.height / this.numYTicks + this.y);
  context.stroke();
 }
 
 // draw values
 context.font = this.font;
 context.fillStyle = "black";
 context.textAlign = "right";
 context.textBaseline = "middle";
 
 for (var n = 0; n < this.numYTicks; n++) {
  var value = Math.round(this.maxY - n * this.maxY / this.numYTicks);
  context.save();
  context.translate(this.x - this.padding, n * this.height / this.numYTicks + this.y);
  context.fillText(value, 0, 0);
  context.restore();
 }
 context.restore();
};

LineChart.prototype.drawLine = function(data, color, width){
 var context = this.context;
 context.save();
 this.transformContext();
 context.lineWidth = width;
 context.strokeStyle = color;
 context.fillStyle = color;
 context.beginPath();
 context.moveTo(data[0].x, data[0].y * this.scaleY);
 
 for (var n = 0; n < data.length; n++) {
  var point = data[n];
  
  // draw segment
  context.lineTo(point.x * this.scaleX, point.y * this.scaleY);
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(point.x * this.scaleX, point.y * this.scaleY, this.pointRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
  // position for next segment
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(point.x * this.scaleX, point.y * this.scaleY);
 }
 context.restore();
};

LineChart.prototype.transformContext = function(){
 var context = this.context;
 
 // move context to center of canvas
 this.context.translate(this.x, this.y + this.height);
 
 // invert the y scale so that that increments
 // as you move upwards
 context.scale(1, -1);
};
window.onload = function(){
var labels = ["07:45","","","","","07:50","","","","","07:55","","","","","08:00","","","","","08:05"];

 var myLineChart = new LineChart({
  canvasId: "mychart",
  minX: 0,
  minY: 0,
  maxX: 21,
  //maxY: 4524,
  maxY: 5000,
  unitsPerTickX: 1,
  unitsPerTickY: 200,
  caption: "Session summary",
  Xcaption: "Minutes",
  Ycaption: "Sessions",
  title: "Sessions",
  labels: labels,
 });

var data = [{x:1, y:2844},{x:2, y:2869},{x:3, y:2891},{x:4, y:2914},{x:5, y:2948},{x:6, y:2967},{x:7, y:2985},{x:8, y:3012},{x:9, y:3029},{x:10, y:3050},{x:11, y:3069},{x:12, y:3097},{x:13, y:3128},{x:14, y:3159},{x:15, y:3192},{x:16, y:3210},{x:17, y:3238},{x:18, y:3267},{x:19, y:3293},{x:20, y:3311}];
myLineChart.drawLine(data, "green", 3);

var data = [{x:1, y:1280},{x:2, y:1283},{x:3, y:1284},{x:4, y:1279},{x:5, y:1278},{x:6, y:1282},{x:7, y:1284},{x:8, y:1284},{x:9, y:1279},{x:10, y:1279},{x:11, y:1282},{x:12, y:1286},{x:13, y:1284},{x:14, y:1280},{x:15, y:1277},{x:16, y:1279},{x:17, y:1286},{x:18, y:1290},{x:19, y:1279},{x:20, y:1278}];
myLineChart.drawLine(data, "yellow", 2);

}
</script></body></html>
```

I did some search but didn't find anything I could add to this code.